# Wordpress : How to count number of posts on a tag

Tags: wordpress, tags, count

I have a question.

How can I count number of posts of a tag ?

Example : 
Tag photos (67)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here.

- [Wordpress - Get number of posts AND comments by day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974412/wordpress-get-number-of-posts-and-comments-by-day)
- [Get number of posts belonging to a particular category,](http://wpprogrammer.com/snippets/get-number-of-posts-belonging-to-a-particular-category-tag-or-custom-taxonomy/)

Answer (score 10):

Use the code below:

```
$taxonomy = "category"; // can be category, post_tag, or custom taxonomy name

// Using Term Slug
$term_slug = 'some-category';
$term = get_term_by('slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy);

// Fetch the count
echo $term->count;
```

Comment: you can use also `get_term_by('name', $term_name, $taxonomy);` or `get_term_by('id', $term_id, $taxonomy);` instead of `slug`