# Include tag count with Wordpress get_tag_link

Tags: php, wordpress, count, tags

I'm using Wordpress, and i'm trying to create an index for a particular part of my site. I'd like to be able to list certain tags (**not** the entire tag list) with their respective post-count in brackets next to each link.

For example, I can get tag #16 to show as a link using:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_tag_link(16); ?>">tagname</a>
```

but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get it to show with the post-count next to it, like 'tagname (20)', etc.

I'm sure there's a simple answer (it seems like it should be easy?) but i've googled every permutation of 'get_tag_link with post count' that I can think of and have come up empty.

Any help would really be appreciated!

Kate.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259817/wordpress-how-to-count-number-of-posts-on-a-tag. You can just echo the count right after the tag name

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use `get_term_by`, then you need to pass in(as the first argument), either the id, slug, or name of the category/term/tag, whatever.

Then you can simply call `->count` on your new object.

```
$term = get_term_by('id', 16, 'post_tag');
```

Then you can simply call:

```
$term->count;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply :) Could you just clarify how i'd actually put this into my code? I'm not great with php, and am just sort of muddling through with most of it. Cheers, Kate.